# integrate hammerJS with emberJS

Tags: ember.js, hammer.js

I'm trying to integrate HammerJS v2.0.2 with EmberJS 1.6.1.

I used many code samples but non of them work, I get different errors. lets take the simplest one. 
I implemented this view:

```
ListApp.ScrollerView = Ember.View.extend({
    setupTap: function() {

        var self = this;
        this.hammer = new Hammer(this.get('element'));

        console.log(this.get('element'));

        var tap = new Hammer.Tap();

        tap.set('enable', true);
        this.hammer.add(tap);

        this.hammer.on('tap', function() {
            console.log('before tap!');
            self.tap();
        });

    }.on('didInsertElement'),

    tap: function() {
        console.log('tap!');
    }
});
```

but I get the following error after the page is loaded:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
```

any idea why I see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Here is working bin with hammer integrated to a view.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cecoyo/2/edit)**

Here's the relevant code on how you integrate hammer into a view

```
App.Hammer = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: 'hammer',

  setupTap: function() {
    Hammer(this.$()[0]).on("tap", this.tap.bind(this));

  }.on('didInsertElement'),

  tap: function() {
    alert('My tamplate name is ' + this.get('templateName'));
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks this works fine, will this make one instance of hammer per element?

Comment: Im not really sure. I havent used hammer, just glanced their getting started guide to make the demo. But if you just want like one instance for the whole app or something, extend the ApplicationView class. Even if it creates another instance, just do the clean up work in the 'willClearRender' hook of a view.

Comment: ok thanks, I will try to track the count of instances and clean it up in proper place